# Getting activeProfiles inside of SwaggerConfig.java file? Trying to disable/hide authorize button in ui on specific profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger, swagger-ui

Using swagger3.0.0.

I have this working code that displays the authorize button and headers for every endpoint, but I'd like to disable them when I'm on a different profile. Instead of creating an entirely new configuration I wanted to handle it when I create my docket.

```
@Bean
public Docket d(){
  Docket dock = new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30);
  docket
    .select()
    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("myapp.test.api"))
    .build()
    .apiInformation(apiinfo())
    //enabling authorize button and setting globally across all endpoints
    .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(authenticationScheme))
    .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));

  return docket;
}
```

The below code is what I'm attempting to do. I thought I could simply get the activeProfile from env and check but I'm getting an error where activeProfiles is null. Is it because of how spring-boot is initialized?

`Cannot invoke "org.springframework.core.env.Environment.getActiveProfiles()" because "this.env" is null`

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
boolean x = Arrays.stream(env.getActiveProfiles()).anyMatch("this_profile"::contains);

@Bean
public Docket d(){
  Docket dock = new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30);
  docket
    .select()
    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("myapp.test.api"))
    .build()
    .apiInformation(apiinfo());
  
  if(x){
    docket
      //enabling authorize button and setting globally across all endpoints
      .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(authenticationScheme))
      .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));
  }

    return docket;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to inline the x variable as if I remember correctly @Autowired won't inject the Environment class by the time you hit the definition of your x variable as it is now.

```
 if(Arrays.stream(env.getActiveProfiles()).anyMatch("this_profile"::contains);){
    docket
      //enabling authorize button and setting globally across all endpoints
      .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(authenticationScheme))
      .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));
  }
```

Comment: worked! thx :) not sure if this is the proper way of doing it but it is good for now